# Send Mail from GMail with PHP; over proxy

Tags: php, gmail

I'm building an internal web-application in PHP that needs the ability to mail.
I've used the code listed here:

[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

and it works like a charm, when I run it from my house.
 However, when I run the code from the office, I get the following:

```
Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (code: -1, response: )]
```

Any idea how to get around this?
Thanks,
-JWW

Comment: It's most probably a firewall at your workplace blocking outgoing connections to port 465.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the responder above - this is most likely a firewall blocking outbound connections on port 465.  You can either try TLS connection on port 587 or port 25 per Gmail's troubleshooting docs : http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775

If you are unable to get around this (if IT will not remove the blocks for example), you could try a third party API as a proxy.  Our product http://PostageApp.com can use external mailservers such as Gmail, in addition to our own MTA, and communication is all through standard http REST calls, avoiding the firewall issue.

We're a paid service but have a free plan as well...if you would be sending more email than our free plan allows for (100/day), then you'll probably fall foul of Gmail's sending limits anyway which restrict third party clients to about 100/day outbound.

http://help.postageapp.com/kb/quick-start-guides/php

Disclaimer: I work for PostageApp

Comment: Tom, thanks for the tip. I'm trying to get everything configured on my end for your service, and I think I'm running into problems with cURL. I'm behind a corporate proxy which appears to be using a proxy authentication script. Do you have any tips? Thank, JWW.

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably a firewall at your workplace blocking outgoing connections to port 465. Did you try port 587 instead?

Comment: ports 587 and 25 both fail. Thanks